# pandas merge_asof error when using float as key

Tags: python, pandas, merge

When using pandas merge_asof as in the following example

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 5.5, 10.9], 'left_val': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.8, 5.4, 5.55, 7.4], 'right_val': [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]})

pd.merge_asof(left, right, on='a', direction='nearest', tolerance=5)
```

I get the error

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
   1363 
   1364             else:
-> 1365                 raise MergeError("key must be integer or timestamp")
   1366 
   1367         # validate allow_exact_matches

MergeError: key must be integer or timestamp
```

It looks weird since in the documentation I read

```
on : label

Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this must be a numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float. On or left_on/right_on must be given
```

so using a float as key should be fine...

I'm using pandas 0.23.0

Comment: this seems no longer a problem, at least from pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the tolerance parameter is only allowed for integer and timedelta values hence the error, it runs fine without.

Maybe you can fix it with a post-processing step to say:

```
right["b"] = right["a"]
df_result = pd.merge_asof(left, right, on='a', direction='nearest')
df_result.loc[abs(df_result["b"]-df_result["a"]) > 5, :] = np.nan
df_result.dropna()
```

This will merge them by nearest then null any rows where the join was above your tolerance (5 in this case) and then you can drop the null rows like the never existed at all...